# C++ Visual Studio 2013 - Windows Phone (access violation error)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, c++-cli

I've got a big problem and sadly I can't solve it. I've added following class to my project:

```
ref class NavigationContext sealed
{
private:
    int combobox1;
    int combobox2;
    int combobox3;



public:
    NavigationContext();



public:
    int rcombobox_1() {
        return combobox1;
    }

};

NavigationContext^ StaticData;
```

And the point is that I get Access Violation error when I try to call "int rcombobox_1()" function. Why? Is there any other way to retrieve data from private variables?

I had to modify your code, because it didn't want to be compiled. Now it looks like that:

```
    ref class NavigationContext sealed
{
private:
    int combobox1;
    int combobox2;
    int combobox3;



private:
    NavigationContext();
    NavigationContext(const NavigationContext^);
    NavigationContext^ operator=(const NavigationContext^);


public:


    static NavigationContext^ instance() {
        static NavigationContext^ theInstance;
        return theInstance;

    }



    int rcombobox_1() {
        return combobox1;
    }

};
```

...and I used your caller line, but it still doesn't work. "&" sign doesn't work in my IDE and I change it into ^, but I don't know whether it was correct move.

Error message: "First-chance exception at 0x00C99331 in Losowanie Lotto.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000010.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

Eventually I've found a solution. The instance of object must be created with line:

```
NavigationContext^ StaticData = ref new NavigationContext();
```

Comment: Your problem is very probably elsewhere than from the code shown. How are you creating an instance of `NavigationContext`?

Comment: with this line: NavigationContext^ StaticData;

Comment: And where did you allocate memory for this pointer?

Comment: Sorry but I'm beginner. How can I do that?

Comment: _"but it still doesn't work."_ Please be specific. Include the error messages verbatim into your question.

Comment: Did I write `static NavigationContext^ instance()`?? Well, that's not valid standard c++ syntax, but refers to [tag:c++-cli] specifically (that's why I've been retagging your question last time).

Comment: Really thanks for help, but your line "static NavigationContext theInstance" was wrong according to my IDE. It couldn't be compiled :(

Comment: Please note this is C++/CX, not C++/CLI (similar syntax, but different technology). Also, I am curious why you are attempting something like this in C++ if you are not familiar with the language; if you are learning C++ I would suggest starting with simple command-line programs.

Answer (score 0):

> *"And the point is that I get Access Violation error when I try to call `int rcombobox_1()` function. Why?"*

You are dereferencing a pointer that isn't assigned to a valid instance of `NavigationContext`.

> *"Is there any other way to retrieve data from private variables?"*

I doesn't have anything to do with your getter function, this is OK.

---

As for the comments

> *"And where did you allocate memory for this pointer?"*
>
> *"Sorry but I'm beginner. How can I do that? "*

It looks like you want to have something like a singleton, rather than a global (uninitialized) pointer:

```
ref class NavigationContext sealed {
private:
    int combobox1;
    int combobox2;
    int combobox3;

    NavigationContext();
    NavigationContext(const NavigationContext&);
    NavigationContext& operator=(const NavigationContext&);

public:
    static NavigationContext& instance() {
        static NavigationContext theInstance; // <<< This statement 
                                              //     allocates the
                                              //     memory.
        return theInstance;
    }
    int rcombobox_1() {
        return combobox1;
    }

};
```

---

Caller syntax:

```
int rcCombo1 = NavigationContext::instance().rcombobox_1();
```

---

There might be other solutions regarding this is tagged [c++-cli](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli) specifically, that take the garbage collection mechanism into account.